# Escape string in elixir

Tags: elixir

Given a String like `str = “\“` and then rendering it into some other program like JS or Python:

```
# index.js.eex
console.log(„<%= str %>“)

# hello.py.eex
print(„<%= str %>“)
```

results in `console.log(„\“)`

You see the problem the backslash will escape the closing quote and produce a syntax error in JS

The question is, How should I fix it?

PS: I am writing it on a mobile phone, so the quotes are not correct, will fix it as soon I am on my laptop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "javascript encode" the string in elixir.

The rules for JS are that a slash needs to be double-escaped. You can do that yourself, or use something like [Phoenix.HTML.javascript_escape](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.html#javascript_escape/1)

`javascript_escape("my string with \")`

See the source code [here](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_html/blob/master/lib/phoenix_html.ex#L184) if interested

Comment: python has different encoding rules, and so you would need a different format. If you are trying to get a string that works across many programming languages, it's better to treat it as _data_ (such as JSON) and then import that into the appropriate code

Comment: This has been renamed [Phoenix.HTML.javascript_escape/1](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.html#javascript_escape/1) in latest versions.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Phoenix you might find these useful
https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.html#escape_javascript/1
https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.html#html_escape/1

Or perhaps convert it to JSON and skip the quotes. Here's an example.

```
# index.js.eex
console.log(<%= raw(Jason.encode!(str)) %>)
```

Perhaps a view helper would be better (example for Phoenix):

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.LayoutView do
  use MyAppWeb, :view

  def raw_json(data) do
    case Jason.encode(data) do
      {:ok, result} -> raw(result)
      {:error, _reason} -> nil # Depending on what fallback you want
    end
  end
end
```